# Celebración para la graduación del sitio en México

Tags: discusión, graduación

Estoy planeando la celebración de nuestra graduación en México pero necesito saber cual ciudad funcionará mejor. La fecha la decidimos luego...pero será en junio.

Por favor contesten con la ciudad en donde podrían asistir.  Votaremos por las que se presenten y sacaré de allí el lugar donde tendremos nuestra celebración.

¡A votar!

<s>La votación terminará el 3 de mayo.</s>

La ciudad en donde tendremos nuestra celebración será

¡Ciudad de México!

---

## Los detalles del evento están aquí: [Celebración de Stack Overflow en español](https://www.eventbrite.com/e/stack-overflow-en-espanol-celebracion-de-graduacion-cdmx-tickets-35150780932)

¡Nos vemos el 16 de junio!

Comment: Necesitamos tambien una celebracion en Colombia!

Comment: @IvanBotero vengan a México, podemos ayudar se queden en algún lugar para que no gasten mucho! (⌐■_■)

Comment: ¿El día que termina la votación también se decide la fecha exacta del evento?

Comment: Supongo que en la votación solo contaran los votos positivos, como en otras encuestas que hemos tenido

Comment: @Rubén parece ser que en esa región no hay mucha actividad en el sitio `--> ` http://data.stackexchange.com/es/query/663474

Comment: @Rubén totalmente de acuerdo, por eso puse "*parece ser que...*" :)

Comment: y los detalles juanm?

Comment: @jasilva estamos tratando de encontrar lugares ahora, teníamos uno en mente pero no se pudo - en cuanto tengamos más detalles los comparto.  Por ahora, la fecha es junio 15

Comment: Para los posibles visitantes > 
[Necesito ayuda para la celebración en México](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2007/2027)

Comment: ¿Por qué está destacada una pregunta sobre un evento que ya ha concluido? Este sito está dejado de la mano de Dios.

Answer (score 19):

Podría asistir fácilmente a una celebración en la **Ciudad de México (CDMX)**.

> 15 - 2 = 13

Comment: No veo alguna razón en especial para votar negativo, ya que como dice @jasilva: *[Supongo que en la votación solo contaran los votos positivos, como en otras encuestas que hemos tenido](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1843/celebraci%C3%B3n-para-la-graduaci%C3%B3n-del-sitio-en-m%C3%A9xico#comment5391_1843)*

Comment: Voto por CDMX porque al ver que todos son del norte no creo que nadie vaya hasta Yucatan !

Comment: @jasilva ¿[Matemáticas a diciembre](https://www.google.com/search?q=11-1)?

Comment: @Mariano Dios mio me va a dar un infarto

Comment: @jasilva No te preocupes, **[nadie lo vio](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nErKw.png)** ;-)

Comment: @Mariano yo -> (ToT)

Comment: entonces los negativos ya cuentan ??

Comment: Para quienes no pueden ver los votos positivos/negativos, en lugar de editar para agregar estos, me parece que es mejor referirlos al time line, que en este caso es  https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/1847/timeline

Comment: Era de esperarse... ganó CDMX (⌐■_■)

Comment: Era de esperarse... puro americanista...

Comment: haha! :) pero si puedes asistir @Toledano

Comment: Ojalá. Depende del día... Si es a finales de mes, si.

Comment: @Jorgesys: Ganaron en esta ocasión, ¡vamos por la revancha! jajaja

Comment: @Mariano no puede ser que esa cosa tenga +5 lo voy a reportar como abusivo ;)

Comment: @jasilva jajajaja... fue gracioso nomás.... puedo borrarlo si preferís

Comment: @Mariano no te preocupes, me enseñara a tener mas cuidado XD

Comment: Si en la ciudad de México

Comment: @SoftMolina revisa el link en donde será el lugar del evento, se llevará a cabo el siguiente viernes 16 :D

Comment: Es el restaurante del buho verdad?

Answer (score 15):

Podría asistir fácilmente a una celebración en **Monterrey**.

> 11 - 1 = 10

Comment: He "llamado a la caballería" :) ->https://www.meetup.com/es/Stack-Overflow-en-Espanol-Monterrey/messages/boards/thread/50780099/0#130375987

Comment: Parece ser que nuestros amigos poblanos se están poniendo las pilas, ya empataron en votos a Mty :)

Comment: Tan calladitos que estaban :P Me pregunto si deberíamos cambiar "Monterrey" por "Ciudad Metropolitana de Nuestra Señora de Monterrey" por lo menos para estar a la par en cuanto formas de nombre de ciudades :P^2

Comment: deberían darnos chance ya tuvieron el meetup en monterrey   :D

Comment: Para quienes no pueden ver los votos positivos/negativos, en lugar de editar para agregar estos, me parece que es mejor referirlos al time line, que en este caso es  https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/1848/timeline

Comment: 10? no llego la caballería! ಠ_ಠ

Comment: @Rubén el timeline sólo muestra negativos a quienes iniciaron sesión y tienen el privilegio.... Pero concuerdo en que no deberíamos agregar la información. Causa bump innecesario y permite ludificar los votos (deja que se puedan modificar los ya emitidos)

Comment: @Mariano: Ups, pensé que el timeline no requería de privilegios. Gracias por sacarme del error. P.D: nadie se quejó de que no pudiera ver el timeline (:

Comment: @Jorgesys: Me parece que no les llegó el mensaje :(

Comment: @Rubén hace muuuucho tiempo te dejaba... aparecieron varios scripts que te "otorgaban el privilegio" simulando el mismo comportamiento que en el sitio, y se modificó para tomar en cuenta la sesión

Comment: @Rubén me hubiera gustado también en Mty, ahora me encuentro aquí, de hecho también voté.

Comment: @Jorgesys: Si no me fuera posible asistir a CDMX, estoy pensando proponer que el siguiente encuentro local coincida a manera de un evento "off-site". Por lo pronto habrá que esperar a noticias de la fecha y del programa del evento.

Answer (score 6):

Podría asistir fácilmente a una celebración en **Guadalajara**

> 3 - 1 = 2

Comment: ¡Guadalajara! siiii

Answer (score 5):

Podría asistir fácilmente a una celebración en **Heróica Puebla de Zaragoza**.

> 5 - 2 = 3

Comment: Ahora que lo mencionas, yo también podría asistir, me queda a poco menos de dos horas. Talvés a @Xique también le interese esta opción.

Comment: Tal vez si le quito mi voto al ex-defectuoso...

Comment: Ya no puedes quitar tu voto jeje, a menos que edite la respuesta del ex-defectuoso :P

Comment: yo voto por esta opción  :)

Comment: Esta opción también es excelente! (⌐■_■)

Comment: @Ruben no puedo ='(

Comment: 4 veces Heróica Puebla de Zaragoza.

Comment: La Ciudad de México antes se llamaba Distrito Federal(DF, el defectuoso)

Comment: ahora es CDMX http://cdmxtravel.com/en/

Comment: Ya nos echaron monterrey los regios... Força Puebla!

Comment: @ReneLimon: Gracias por la aclaración sobre lo "de-efe-ctuoso", no sé que traigo, que no me dí cuenta.

Comment: Perdón por meterme aquí y si la pregunta no es adecuada, ¿es Puebla de Zaragoza la misma ciudad de los pipopes?

Comment: @Shaz pensé eras canadiense, de que parte de México eres?

Comment: @jorgesys no soy mexicano, soy canadiense.

Comment: @Shaz ok tienes ascendencia Méxicana porque comentas de puebla.

Comment: @Shaz pipope es una especie de grosería, pero aquí nos lo tomamos con humor

Comment: @Jorgesys tampoco soy de ascendencia mexicana, mis raíces son de América del Sur.

Comment: Gracias por la explicación @ReneLimon , mi intención no es ofender a nadie, solo preguntaba.

Comment: @Shaz a mi no me ofende aunque nací aquí, nosotros lo traducimos como piezas poblanas perfectas jajaja

Comment: al parecer ya ganamos  :´)

Comment: Hay que esperar, el último minuto también tiene 60 segundos...

Answer (score 5):

Podría asistir fácilmente a una celebración en **Sinaloa**

> 3 - 1 = 2

Answer (score 4):

Podría asistir fácilmente a una celebración en **Queretaro**

Answer (score 3):

Podría asistir fácilmente a una celebración en **Playa del carmen**

> 3 - 0 = 3

Comment: @Mariano LOL XD