# ¿Han cambiado la reputación mínima para las revisiones?

Tags: soporte, graduación, privilegios

Hoy al entrar en en el sitio me he fijado que no se me permitía acceder a las revisiones, me he puesto a mirar y he visto que ahora necesitas 500 de reputación para *Respuestas tardías y Primeras publicaciones* por lo que ya no tengo acceso.

¿Cual es el motivo de este cambio?

Comment: Eso pasa cuando uno crece :')

Comment: @dwarandae es un querer y no poder lo de crecer en SO, me sigue pareciendo una burrada cuando veo a gente con 5k de reputación.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Efectivamente, cambiaron todos los privilegios. El sitio **dejó de ser beta** y se graduó.

Este es el listado de los nuevos privilegios: https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges.

**Información acerca de la graduación:**

- Anuncio de la graduación: [¡Stack Overflow en español se gradúa hoy!](https://stackoverflow.blog/2017/05/17/stack-overflow-en-espanol-se-gradua-hoy)
- [¿Qué cambia cuando el sitio pasa de beta a graduado?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1810/127)
- [Celebración para la graduación del sitio en España](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1844/127)
- [Celebración para la graduación del sitio en México](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1843/127)