# Necesito ayuda para la celebración en México

Tags: discusión, graduación, encuentros-locales

Estoy planeando y preparando la celebración para el **16 junio** pero necesito preguntarles por ayuda en esto. Teníamos un lugar casi listo pero no se realizó...ahora necesito pedirles por recomendaciones en lugares donde podamos tener nuestro evento.

Estoy buscando lugares específicamente asociados con sus centros de trabajo.  Si tienen acceso a lugares donde nos podemos juntar, por favor háganmelo saber. Puedo platicar con ustedes en privado para discutir los detalles pero necesito tener algunas opciones.

¿Me ayudan?

Comment: 15 de junio es jueves :'(

Comment: ¿En qué ciudad tenías pensado organizar la celebración?

Comment: en la Ciudad de Mexico

Comment: la fecha se cambia para el 16 de junio - un viernes ;)

Comment: @JuanM ese día 16 junio estaría en Monterey, México, no se podría cambiar la sede por "problemas de logística" hehe! (⌐■_■)  y te ayudo a organizar y buscar un lugar apropiado, creo que Rubén estaría también interesado...

Comment: que ganas de vivir en mexico :(

Answer (score 4):

No es mi centro de trabajo, pero sé de dos lugares donde realizan reuniones de comunidades parecidas a esta.

Los chavos del grupo [FreeCodeCamp CDMX](https://www.facebook.com/groups/free.code.camp.mexico.df/) y los de [Facebook Developers Circle CDMX](https://www.facebook.com/groups/DevCCiudaddeMexico/?fref=mentions) arman sus <strike>pedas</strike> reuniones en las instalaciones de la empresa [Nearsoft Inc.](https://www.facebook.com/pages/Nearsoft-Inc/850925748272676) .

Yo nunca he ido, pero el lugar se ve bastante bien y su ubicación es muy buena: a media cuadra de Insurgentes sur, a la altura de la estación de metrobus Sonora.

Se ven muy entusiastas... digo, para tratar de juntar a los FreeCodeCampers de la Ciudad de México, ya es mucho amor al arte, pero me parece que podría ser el mismo esquema que la <strike>peda</strike> reunión que armaste para Madrid... son buena gente y hasta pienso que podrían ser una buena adición a la comunidad.

Dejo unas fotos:

Veo tres paredes con proyectores:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Parece que trapean seguido y hay espacio pa'l danzón.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

---

<sub>[Centraal](http://centraal.com) está bien padriuris y está en la *Condechi*, pero se ve más cariñoso.</sub>.

> #### Queja
>
> ¿Por qué en jueves? Que gacho.

Comment: "Parece que trapean seguido y hay espacio pa'l danzón". hehe (⌐■_■)

Comment: Tus plegarias han sido atendidas, será el viernes 16 :D

Comment: La verdad yo quería el sábado ='(. Para no pedir el día y mi regreso a la tierra del faisán y del venado.

Comment: @toledano ¡gracias por la info! te lo agradezco - en cuanto regrese de Madrid, lo investigo a fondo